# UITableView subview appears in wrong section when scrolling?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

In a UITableView I add a UIView as subview but ONLY for section 1. Section 1's content is loaded from a plist and the plist contains mutable content. If there are enough rows to allow scrolling, then the following happens: I scroll to the bottom, and back up, and the UITextField appears randomly on some of section 0's cells. I have no clue why this is happening! So what i do is this (in ´cellForRowAtIndexPath´):

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    //do stuff
}
else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    d = [UIView alloc] init];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:d];
}
```

and this gets totally messed up when I scroll. The subviews appear in section 0 where they shoudnt, and on `didSelectRowAtIdexPath` I reload for section 1 and then subviews even appear twice (over each other)... Its a complete MESS! Please, Please help.......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing any code this seems to be an issue pertaining to reusable cells. What happens is that the cells that have scrolled off the screen are reused for the new content that is to be shown. So i reckon you need to make a distinction in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for section 0 and 1 and basically use different set of cells for them.

EDIT: Ok ima give a shot to your problem here

```
UITableViewCell *cell;

if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellWithoutSubview"];
    if (cell ==nil ) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain reuseIdentifier:@"CellWithoutSubview"] autorelease];
    }

    //do stuff with cell like set text or whatever
}
else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellWithSubview"];
    if (cell ==nil ) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain reuseIdentifier:@"CellWithSubview"] autorelease];

        d = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:d];
        [d release];
    }


}

return cell;
```

So now you'll have two types of cells for the tableview that'll be reused one without the subview and one with the subview.

Comment: what do you mean by different sets of cells?

Comment: I've tried to explain with code what I meant by different set of cells.

Comment: Cheers mate, that code really helped me out and solved the problem! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You must be using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. The purpose of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is to use less memory. If the screen can fit 4 or 5 table cells, then with reuse you only need to have 4 or 5 table cells allocated in memory even if the table has 1000 entries.

So the subviews in `UITableViewCell` are also cached. So when the cell is reused, you need to clean out the old view & then put in the new content.

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"your-id"];
if (cell)
{
     //reusing old cell. reset all subviews before putting new content.
}
else
{
     //Create a fresh new cell
}
```

Comment: how do you clear the subviews? i've been trying to do this using removeFromSuperView but its not working

Comment: you dont need to clear subview. You need to reset them so that old data is no longer there. `removeFromSuperView` is not an option...

Answer (score -1):

You should use `switch` instead:

```
switch ( indexPath.section )
{
    case 0:
    {
        /* do soemthing */
    }
        break;
    case 1:
    {
        d = [UIView alloc] init];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:d];
    }
        break;
}
```

Comment: nah, it was obvious that it's not going to solve my problem, it is basically just another way of using ´if () {} else if () {} else {}´... statements. Still thanx!